# The Differential answer,i calculated, is not the same as the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

The question is on first picuture,and the part of solution is on the second picture.I am not quite understand the second picture meaning

(1)
 [image]

(2)

[image]

The differential of $g(z)$ ,$g'(z)$, should be $\frac{-e^{-z}}{(1+e^{-z})^2}$,why is the $g'(z)$ equal to $a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$,then $$g'(z)=-(1+e^{-z})^{-2}(-e^{-z})=\frac{e^{-z}}{(1+e^{-z})^2}$$
Notice that there is no negative sign.

\begin{align}
g'(z) &= \frac{e^{-z}}{(1+e^{-z})^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}\cdot \frac{e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}} \\
&= a\cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}\right)\\
&= a(1-a)
\end{align}

where I let $a=g(z)$.